# ADO .NET Getting record count

Tags: vb.net, ado

I opened a record from MySQL like this.

```
    Connection1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Connection1.Open(DB_CONNECTIONSTRING)

    RS1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    strSQL1 = "SELECT ... =" & Request.QueryString("ID")

    RS1.Open(strSQL1, Connection1, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText)
```

everything is working well if there's a record. but when there's no record, it gives an error "EOF or BOF is not true or the record is empty". I'm trying to do something like this so that if recordset is empty, it will show 0.00. if not, it'll show the amount.

```
    If RS1.recordcount = "1" Then
        amount = RS1.fields("item1").value.ToString()
    Else
        amount= 0.00
    End If
```

how do I go about? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can test the EOF property of the RecordSet and then follow with your conditional processing.

[RecordSet Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675787(v=vs.85).aspx)

Possible option:

```
    amount = 0.0
    If Not RS1.EOF Then
        If RS1.RecordCount > 0 Then
            amount = RS1.fields("item1").value.ToString()
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: RecordCount is a float type. Not String. Maybe it would be better if the condition was checking for a value greater than 0. Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks. Updated as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of Mort's answer [Mort's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31848598/2645091)  the `RS1.recordcount="1"` should be `RS1.RecordCount > 0`. Object Type is wrong here.

Possible option upgrade:

```
amount = 0.0
If Not RS1.EOF Then
    If RS1.RecordCount > 0 Then
        amount = RS1.fields("item1").Value.ToString()
    End If
End If
```